# Get Jenkins job status by using curl

Tags: bash, curl, jenkins

I know, that there is a way to enable or disable jenkins job by using commands

```
curl -u user:password -X POST http://server/job/jobname/enable
curl -u user:password -X POST http://server/job/jobname/disable
```

But what I need - is to get the status of job "enabled/disables" and write it to the bash $status variable.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if job is enabled or disabled using the API

```
http://server:port/job/jobname/api/xml?xpath=*/buildable
```

So, with crumb, you can use something like this:

```
CRUMB=$(curl -s 'http://USER:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')

myStatus=$(curl -X POST -H "$CRUMB" "http://USER:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/job/jobname/api/xml?xpath=*/buildable")
```

And in variable `myStatus` you get

```
<buildable>true</buildable>
```

or

```
<buildable>false</buildable>
```